# How to get access token for Microsoft Graph for logged in user?

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a .net Core 2 web app with Angular 5 frontend using Azure AD for authentication.

We have based our Graph implementation off of the aspnetcore connect sample.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample

We have two implementations of their GetUserAccessTokenAsync method in the GraphAuthProvider.cs

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample/blob/master/MicrosoftGraphAspNetCoreConnectSample/Helpers/GraphAuthProvider.cs

We are able to get the token for the app, see bottom snippet, but the one below for retrieving the token for the logged in user is throwing the ServiceException.

Obviously the array of Users in the cca variable does not contain any users but we cannot figure out why. Are there any examples of using Microsoft Graph on a web api backend called from a Angular frontend?

Due to additional server side processing we need the calls to go through the web-api so we cannot call directly to Graph for these.

**Gets Graph access token on behalf of logged in user**

```
 public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync(string userId)
    {
        _userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userId, _memoryCache).GetCacheInstance();

        var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            _clientId,
            _redirectUri,
            _credential,
            _userTokenCache,
            null);

        if (!cca.Users.Any()) throw new ServiceException(new Error
        {
            Code = "TokenNotFound",
            Message = "User not found in token cache. Maybe the server was restarted."
        });

        try
        {
            var result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, cca.Users.First());
            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(new Error
            {
                Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                Message = "Caller needs to authenticate. Unable to retrieve the access token silently."
            });
        }
    }
```

**Gets Application Graph access Token**

```
 public async Task<string> GetClientAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        _appTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(_clientId, _memoryCache).GetCacheInstance();

        var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            _clientId,
            _clientAuthority,
            _redirectUri,
            _credential,
            null,
            _appTokenCache);


        try
        {
            var result = await cca.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(_appScopes);
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(new Error
            {
                Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                Message = "Unable to authenticate. Unable to retrieve the access token for client."
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to post this in that project's repo. They seem pretty responsive to questions/issues with the sample: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample/issues

Comment: Maybe a tad late, but it seems you're using the SessionTokenCache for your userTokens and AppTokens. You do switch them out, e.g. leaving the other null, but this comment at the bottom of the page [(Important: don't use the same cache instance for both arguments!)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications) comes to mind for me.